# intuitive understanding when negating quantifiers with sets ("for some" to "union")

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following statements regarding union and their equivalent statements ($\alpha$ indexes a family of sets $A_\alpha$):

- $x \in \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha \iff x \in A_\alpha \text{ for some } \alpha$
- $x \notin \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha \iff x \notin A_\alpha \text{ for all } \alpha$

And the following for intersection:

- $x \in \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha \iff x \in A_\alpha \text{ for all } \alpha$
- $x \notin \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha \iff x \notin A_\alpha \text{ for some } \alpha$

So far so good.

---

Now consider the following, which uses the above results, where $A_\alpha$ are subsets of $X$:

$$\begin{align}x \in X \setminus (\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha) &\iff (x \in X) \land (x \notin \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha) \\ \\ &\iff  (x \in X) \land (x \notin A_\alpha \text{ for all } \alpha) \\ \\ &\iff \bigcap_\alpha (X \setminus A_\alpha) \end{align}$$

The last step seems to make sense to me - the "for all $\alpha$" translates into an intersection. (It is possible my confidence in understanding this is flawed!)

---

Now the following I have trouble with:

$$\begin{align}x \in X \setminus (\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha) &\iff (x \in X) \land (x \notin \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha) \\ \\ &\iff  (x \in X) \land (x \notin A_\alpha \text{ for some } \alpha) \\ \\ &\iff \bigcup_\alpha (X \setminus A_\alpha) \end{align}$$

The last step can be done by mechanistically applying the algebra of logic, but **it doesn't make intuitive sense** to me.

**Question:** How should I think of the last step so that I can perform similar steps in future without doubting its correctness?

---

**My attempt:**

Let me try to make the last step in smaller steps:

$$\begin{align}
(x \in X) \land (x \notin A_\alpha \text{ for some } \alpha)
&\iff (\text{ for some } \alpha: x \in X \land x \notin A_\alpha ) \\ \\ 
&\iff x \in \bigcup_\alpha X \setminus A_\alpha )
\end{align}$$

I'm not fully satisfied with this, but is the closest I can get to explaining where the $\bigcup$ comes from.

Comment: The reasoning you describe under the heading of “my attempt” looks totally correct to me. It’s not clear to me why you wouldn’t be satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example with $\bigcap_\alpha$ is correct. If you want some intuition, think of an intersection over an index $\alpha$ as multi-ary AND statement. If your index had just finitely many values $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ then the statement "for all $\alpha$, $x \in A_\alpha"$ translates to an AND of $k$ statements: "$x \in A_{\alpha_1}$ AND ... AND $x \in A_{\alpha_n}$". Of course you might object that you cannot write infinitely many AND statements, but that's exactly what the universal quantifiers let you do!

For your second example, think of a union over an index $\alpha$ as a multi-ary OR statement, and then remember de Moivre's formula. For finitely many values of $\alpha$ one might have
$$P \,\, AND \,\, (Q_1 \,\, OR \,\, Q_2 \,\, OR \,\, ... \,\, OR \,\, Q_k) = $$
$$(P \,\, AND \,\, Q_2) \,\, OR \,\, (P \,\, AND \,\, Q_2) \,\, OR \,\, ... \,\, OR \,\, (P \,\, AND \,\, Q_k)
$$
And to do this with infinitely many OR statements, well, that's exactly what existential quantifiers let you do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the symbols try to reason it out with natural language. The first two implications are simply expanding what is meant by the symbols.

For the last implication, if $x \in X$ and there exist an $A_\alpha$ that does not contain $x$ then $x$ is not in the intersection of the $A_\alpha$. So there is some $X\setminus A_\alpha$ that does contain $x$. Therefore $x$ must be in the union of the $A_\alpha$ which is what was to be shown.